# Open new named jupyter notebook from terminal

Tags: terminal, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I can open an existing jupyter notebook with a single command (from the [docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/notebook.html#introduction)):

> When starting a notebook server from the command line, you can also open a particular notebook directly, bypassing the dashboard, with `ipython notebook my_notebook.ipynb`. The `.ipynb` extension is assumed if no extension is given.

However, when I want to open a new notebook it seems as if I have to follow 3 steps:

1. Run `ipython notebook`.
2. Open a new notebook by clicking `New > Python 3`. [image: create new notebook]
3. Edit the name of the notebook [image: rename notebook]

## Question

Is there a command that allows me to combine these 3 steps in a single command, similar to the command to open existing notebooks? E.g., something like this pseudo code: `ipython notebook --new my_notebook.ipynb`.

Answer (score 1):

Using this command you can create and open a new notebook without getting into the application. This command will work only in Linux operating system

```
jupyter notebook $(cat Untitled.ipynb >filename.ipynb && echo filename.ipynb)
```